# How to fix typing in hibernate "findBy" for enums?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, enums

I have an entity like so

```
public class SomeClass {

    @NonNull
    @NotNull
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Convert(converter = SomeEnumConverter.class)
    private SomeEnum fieldName;
}
```

I want to be able to find row in DB where the name of the enum matches to the string/enum which I pass. This table has only 2 columns. UUID which is PK and fieldName which is a varchar. I tried the following repository methods.

```
public interface SomeClassRepository extends AnotherRepository<SomeClass, UUID> {

    Optional<SomeClass> findByFieldName(SomeEnum param);

}
```

```
public interface SomeClassRepository extends AnotherRepository<SomeClass, UUID> {

    Optional<SomeClass> findByFieldName(String param);

}
```

My problem is if I try to find by passing a String (2nd case) it complains that my passed value is not the expected type(SomeEnum).
On the other hand if  I pass the enum directly, It tries to look for rows with PK(UUID) = enum which I passed instead of searching on the other column(fieldName varchar). How do I get past this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SomeClass {

@Column(nullable = false)
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private SomeEnum fieldName;
```

}

public interface SomeClassRepository extends AnotherRepository<SomeClass, UUID> {

```
Optional<SomeClass> findByFieldName(SomeEnum param);
```

}

Please try this. This should work